# Android Studio Imported SVG file (resulting XML) crashes the app (Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException)

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

I imported a SVG file to my Android project. I try to display the resulting xml. It keeps crashing the app. The interesting thing is I have other vector assets in SVG format that I've imported and been using the xml(s) that Android studio generated. They're all working fine except this one specific SVG. Any thoughts on why this could be happening? I'd appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

Below are the links to the SVG asset and a simple android project that just displays it.

[Link to SVG file](https://github.com/tettk/svg-imported-failure/blob/master/app/src/main/assets/loader.svg)

[Link to simple android app that just displays the asset](https://github.com/tettk/svg-imported-failure)

Below is the error message I'm getting.

> 2019-12-11 16:41:12.418 11489-11489/com.svg.failure E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.svg.failure, PID: 11489
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.svg.failure/com.svg.failure.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class ImageView
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class ImageView
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class ImageView
>        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.svg.failure:drawable/ic_loader with resource ID #0x7f060062
>        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_loader.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f060062
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:847)
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:631)
>           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:897)
>           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:955)
>           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930)
>           at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:189)
>           at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:172)
>           at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
>           at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:107)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
>           at com.svg.failure.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)

Answer (score -1):

This exception will display if you forgot it:

```
mImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Comment: I don't think that's the case with me here. Please check the links (they're to github), I'm not even accessing the image views from the code side. It's just loaded in the XML layout.

Answer (score -1):

I'll keep updating this until I resolve it.

So far, I have tried to comment out paths in the xml file. There seems to be one path (the first path) that's extremely long. That one path draws the entire vehicle. Commenting the first (very long) path solved the issue. So now I'm trying to go back to the person who provided me the SVG file to see if we can break the line up so it would effectively break up the one long path to multiple shorter paths.

I'll update with result.